# Какой инструмент выбрать для создания формы в веб?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Требуется создать форму для уже существующего сайта для регистрации клиента. Форма должна записывать данные в SQL. Какой инструмент лучше выбрать в среде Visual Studio для создания такой формы?

Comment: *для уже существующего сайта* -- а он на чём написан?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, `WindowsFormsApplication` вполне подойдет для этого. Можно добавить на форму `DataGridView` ну и связать с базой через `BindingSourse`
(все эти элементы есть в `Toolbox`). 
Ну или можно использовать `WPF` , он более гибкий. Для сайта будет лучше. Там тоже есть DataGrid'ы необходимые.

Comment: Спасибо! Большое, пожалуй поаробую windowsforms

Comment: @OlegIaremchuk т.е. необходимо Desktop приложения для наполнения БД?